# Orbits of conjugation on matrices with fixed characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

> Fix a monic polynomial $p\in F[x]$. Let $F$ be a field, and let $Z
>  \subset M_n (F)$ be the collection of matrices with characteristic
>   polynomial $p$. Then $\text{GL}_n (F)$ acts on $Z$ by conjugation. How
>   many orbits are there of this group action?

If $F$ is algebraically closed, then the problem is just counting the number of possible Jordan normal forms. But what if $F$ is not algebraically closed?

Comment: I don't see any real difference if $F$ is not algebraically closed. You still need to know the numbers of irreducible factors and their multiplicities, and the number of orbits is the product of the partition numbers of the multiplicities.

Comment: The rational canonical form can be used over an arbitrary field.

Comment: See [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form).